# Javascript Object.create is not inheriting from the parent

Tags: javascript, object, prototypal-inheritance

I want the man object inherits from the person object. I could have done it using the new operator, but it should work with `Object.create`. But why it is not working? The `console.log` says `undefined` instead of the expected `hello`.

```js
function person() {
    this.say="hello";
}

function man() {
    this.name="John Miler";
}

man.prototype = Object.create(person);

var Johnny = new man();

console.log(Johnny.say);
```

Comment: The 1st `parameter` of `Object.create` should be **prototype**, not _constructor_ (as you supplied). Pass `person.prototype` instead of `person`

Comment: However the 1st parameter is used to copy **methods** rather than _properties_. In order to populate properties, you have to supply the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @hindmost The first parameter can be any object, even `{}` or also `null`. All the properties in that object will be inherited, no matter which of the type they are.

Comment: @Teemu Ok. Let me rephrase it: It is supposed to be a prototype of a newly-created object. It can be almost anything. However in the case of passing constructor, it will be treated in a wrong way (not what the OP expects).

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is two-fold.

## Problem 1:

`Object.create` should be passed the `prototype`, not the constructor. In this case, you should use `Object.create(person.prototype);`, not `Object.create(person);`

---

## Problem 2:

The `say` property is added when the constructor is called, and you never call the parent constructor from the child constructor.

There are a couple ways to solve this, depending on your desired behavior.

### Option 1, `call` parent constructor.

```
person.call(this);
```

#### Sample:

```js
function person() {
    this.say="hello";
}

function man() {
    person.call(this);
    this.name="John Miler";
}

man.prototype = Object.create(person.prototype);

var Johnny = new man();

console.log(Johnny.say);
```

### Option 2, make it a static property.

```
person.prototype.say = "hello";
```

#### Sample:

```js
function person() {
}
person.prototype.say = "hello";

function man() {
    this.name="John Miler";
}

man.prototype = Object.create(person.prototype);

var Johnny = new man();

console.log(Johnny.say);
```

Comment: @Zephyrs For proper prototypical inheritance (ie. the `instanceof` keyword), you would still need to use `Object.create` in addition to `.call`. If you don't want the property to change, using a static property is the correct solution. However, if you want it to be dynamic, using `.call` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If what you try to achieve is for a man object to inherit a person object, try this:

```
// superclass
function Person() {
  this.say = "hello";
}

// superclass method
Person.prototype.doStuff = function() {
  console.info('Stuff done.');
};

// subclass
function Man() {
  Person.call(this); // call super constructor.
  this.name="John Miler";
}

// subclass extends superclass
Man.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Man.prototype.constructor = Man;


var Johnny = new Man();

console.log(Johnny.say); // hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.create should be passed the prototype not the constructor.

```
function person() {
 this.say="hello";
}

function man() {
 this.name="John Miler";
}

man.prototype = Object.create(new person());

var Johnny = new man();

console.log(Johnny.say);
```

Comment: You say that the prototype should be passed, but in the code you're passing an instance???

Comment: By prototype I mean the base object, not the prototype property